# Cómo imprimir números de tres en tres?

Tags: javascript, html5

Escribir un programa que lea dos números x && y (x < y). Imprimir la secuencia de uno en uno de x hasta y pero imprimiendo en lineas de 3 en 3.

Se como hacer que imprima de uno en uno hasta el número y

¿Pero como logro que sea en lineas de tres  en tres?

```
<script>
    var x = prompt("x");
    var y = prompt("y");

    for (i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        document.write(i);
    }
</script>
```

---

```
x=1 y=9
```

debe imprimir de uno en número pero con lineas de tres números

```
1 2 3 (salto de linea) 
4 5 6 (salto de linea) 
7 8 9
```

Comment: for (let i = x; i <= y; i++)

Comment: Pero cual es la duda en que te estas deteniendo,

Comment: @MiguelZarate si ingreso x=1 y y=12
Debe imprimir de esta manera, haciendo salto de linea cada 3 numeros

1    2   3  (salto de linea)                   
4    5   6  (salto de linea)                             
7    8   9  (salto de linea)                 
10 11 12  (salto de linea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador módulo `%` puede ser útil:

```js
// var x = prompt("x");
// var y = prompt("y");
x = 5;
y = 9;
idx = 0;
linea = '';
for (i = x; i <= y; i++) {
  idx++
  linea += `${i} `;
  if (0 == idx % 3) {
    document.write(linea + '<br/>');
    linea = '';
  }
}
// el resto
document.write(linea + '<br/>');
```